# How to detect swipe for parent view when have multiple child?

Tags: java, android

I have a custom calendar layout that forms by multiple Linear layouts. when I set OnTouchListener to the parent view. It's not working because they are filled with child view. and I can't add the listener to each child view because It's a lot to set. Any solution that can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out intercepting touch events is not as simple and straightforward as the [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html) would have us believe. To properly handle touch events in the `ViewGroup`, you'll need to override both `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and `onTouchEvent()` (if you don't want your child views to get the touch events as well).

The [reference docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) for `onInterceptTouchEvent()` explain this in a much cleaner manner than the guide. Here's an [article](http://neevek.net/posts/2013/10/13/implementing-onInterceptTouchEvent-and-onTouchEvent-for-ViewGroup.html) that has the relevant code along with descriptions.

**TL;DR** - Once you intercept the touch event in `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and return true, the following touch events are sent to `onTouchEvent()` of your parent viewgroup. If you return false in `onInterceptTouchEvent()`, the following touch events are sent to the `onTouchEvent()` of the child views which you can continue to intercept in `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.

---

You need to override `onInterceptTouchEvent()` in your custom calendar layout and do your touch handling there. Refer to the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup) for further reference.

> The `onInterceptTouchEvent()` method is called whenever a touch event is detected on the surface of a `ViewGroup`, including on the surface of its children. If `onInterceptTouchEvent()` returns true, the `MotionEvent` is intercepted, meaning it is not passed on to the child, but rather to the `onTouchEvent()` method of the parent.

Comment: sorry for late reply. I tried this callback already and it can only detect up and down event also for up and down when I logged how it does, It always called down - up concurrently every time

Comment: Try checking if any of your child views are explicitly preventing touch interception using `requestDisallowTouchIntercept`.

Comment: I think I might have found out the reason as to why it doesn't work. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try +1 for nice referencing.

Comment: Cool, mark the answer as correct if it works. Cheers. :)